# Does any Purāna (or other scripture) mention the name of all 18,000 kalp?

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, kalpa

Per verified sources, it's said that we are in the 1st day of the 51st year of the present Brahma, which means that 18,000 Brahma days or Kalp have elapsed. Do any Purānas or other scriptures mention the names of all 18,000 kalp?